# Run AirPort Utility 5.6.1 in High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, airport

I would like to install the Airport version 5.6.1 on MacBook with High Sierra.

It already has the Airport Version 6.3.8 installed.

Can I have both installed and without removing the 6.3.8 and use the 5.6.1 instead.

Comment: I think I got answer for this will write soon but not sure if it will work for this version

Comment: I've tried dragging it from an old computer to a new one, but it won't run on newer computers. I'll be interested to see if you get it working. There's no other way for me to configure my 3 old airport expresses and one old saucer-shaped airport extremes. They each all work and have their continued uses. I play music all throughout my house with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without modifying your system.

Use something like Pacifier to extract the AirPort Utility.app and Apple80211.framework from the installer.

Then, run these two commands in Terminal whenever you want to use it (substituting the correct paths obviously):

```
$ export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=<path-to-older-Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211>
$ /path-to/AirPort\ Utility\ 5.6.1.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPort\ Utility
```

I keep that older framework and older app in the same folder, save the following AppleScript as an app (it expects to be in the same folder too), and just double-click it to launch:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set base_folder to (container of (path to me) as alias)
    set base_path to POSIX path of base_folder
    set library_path to base_path & "Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211"
    set library_exists to exists (library_path as POSIX file)
end tell

if library_exists then

    do shell script "export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=" & quoted form of library_path & "
" & quoted form of (base_path & "AirPort Utility 5.6.1.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPort Utility")

else

    display alert "Apple80211.framework could not be found" message "The library was not found in " & base_path & "."

end if
```

This works all the way up to Mojave.

Comment: Interesting..will have to try it. Can you provide more explanation for example,  Is the purpose of the script to switch from new Airport to old, and back ? or just for the case of system restart where it will automatically load the new version.  I would like the option of been able to switch, since do not plan to use the older version all the time, only when debugging WiFi.  You deserve the 50 points award for the effort.

Comment: By default, the system looks for libraries in /System. However, by setting the environment variable DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, you can specify other locations JUST for that Terminal/shell. This means you're only dynamically loading the older framework for use with what is run within that Terminal before closing it. The script only automates those two lines in a Terminal/shell, and gives you something double-clickable for those that might be Terminal-averse, or just looking for convenience. None of the above affects the new AirPort Utility or your system in any way. You can run them concurrently.

Answer (score -2):

Just start with the version offered, configure it and after that Apple recognise it and ask you to upgrade to a new version - I have installed on two devices this year, on High Sierra. The actual version is 6.3.8

[image]

Comment: That is not what the question is about. I want specifically the Version 5.6.1 installed and running.